# Receiving sms from custom application

Tags: android

I am working on an application in which i am sending an `sms` from a device to itself. Now i want to read it from my application. I know how to read it but i also read from the developer page that only one (default) `sms` application will be able to read the `sms`. If that's the case how can my application can read the `sms` that is sent by my application.

To Receive `SMS` i am using broadcast receiver which is registered in the `manifest.xml`.

-THANKS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...read from the developer page that only one (default) sms application will be able to read the sms.

Nope. Your app can still both receive and read incoming SMS in KitKat and above using the standard methods (barring any alterations to the standard behavior by the vendor). The changes to the SMS API are a little confusing, but it mainly boils down to the fact that non-default apps cannot *write* to the Provider. Any app with the `RECEIVE_SMS` permission can still get messages as they arrive. Also, this broadcast can no longer be aborted, so any and all Receivers registered to do so will receive it. Furthermore, any app with the `READ_SMS` permission can still read messages from the Provider. As mentioned, they just can't write to it to save messages or update their status.

As testimonial, my device runs KitKat 4.4.4, and I use it to send messages to itself all the time for testing, all from non-default apps.

Comment: @UsmanRiaz If you're having problems getting your Receiver to work, you'll have to post your manifest and the code.